# Latch inference in systemverilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I was trying a system verilog code , and there is a latch inference which is an error for asic flow .

```
m_f1=m1[10]?(m1[9:1]):(m1[8:0]);
e=m1[10]?(e+1):e; 
m_f = m_f1;
```

here the error or latch inference is at m_f=m_f1 , the only other place it is being used is at

```
always@(posedge clk) begin
  c[15]=s3;
  c[8:0]=m_f;
  c[14:9]=e;
end
```

Comment: Looks like `e` is the latch inference.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by @dave_59 in the comments, the latch inference comes from feedback around this mux
`e =m1[10] ? (e + 1) : e ;`

The schematic representation would look like this:
[image]

Its plain to see that this is feedback around combinational logic (a multiplexer aka mux) which is also known as a latch.

Its ok to use the mux to select between `e` and `e + 1`, but its not ok to feed them back around the mux.

You can put a register in the feedback path (if that is the behavior you want) and the warnings about latches will go away.  Sometimes accumulators or incrementers look like feedback around mux, however you will need a register to model this properly.

The same circuit with the register might look like this:
[image]

This would allow you to load e, then add 1 to it using the select m1[10].
The 2nd drawing shows the register concept only, modify your code to behave as needed, but without the combinationalfeedback around the mux.

Comment: But the error I inferred was at m_f , that is where the latch inference is at .

Comment: @Adrikx Please provide a small and complete module so that we can reproduce the result you are seeing. See [minimal-reproducable-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  I want to be able to run your code in a Vivado synthesis flow and observe the error you are seeing.